# Jquery - hover() e mouseleave()

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou com um problema.

Tenho duas div com uma certa distância entre elas. Eu gostaria de que quando eu posicionar o mouse na primeira div, a segunda div apareça e eu consiga passar o mouse de uma para a outra sem a segunda div sumir. Só sumir quando o mouse estiver fora de ambas.

Eu sei que eu poderia colocar tudo isso dentro de uma div maior e programar o evento para essa div. Mas na minha aplicação, a div que vai aparecer no hover() está em outra parte do código e eu preciso que seja assim.

Segue o fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hbp7kfp2/3/

HTML

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
}
#div2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$('#div1, #div2').hover(function(){
    $('#div2').show();
});

$('#div1, #div2').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#div2').hide();
});
```

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: então, seu código já faz isso, quando você coloca o mouse entre os dois quadrados(divs) ele esta nessa condição(fora de ambos), deseja que o programa faça tipo um delay, um retardo para que dê tempo de você chegar com o mouse até a outra div ?

Comment: @SneepSNinjA, isso mesmos. Acho que essa seria a forma adequada. Como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com delay resolve assim:

```
    var vermelho = 0;
var azul = 0;
$('#div2').hover(function(){
    $('#div2').show();   
    azul = 1;
});

$('#div1').hover(function(){
    $('#div2').show();
    vermelho =1;    
});

function fechar(){    
    if(vermelho==0 && azul==0){ $('#div2').hide(); }    
}

$('#div1').mouseleave(function(){    
    vermelho=0;
    setTimeout(function(){ fechar(); },1000);    
});

$('#div2').mouseleave(function(){    
    azul=0;
    setTimeout(function(){ fechar(); },1000);    
});
```

Comment: Esqueci de comentar no código o valor 1000 é igual a 1 segundo (1000 miléssimo de segundo) se precisar ajustar o delay

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente.
Preciso fazer algo aqui para aumentar sua reputação?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hbp7kfp2/5/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
$('#div1').hover(function() {
  $('#div2').show();
}).mouseout(function() {
  $('#div2').show();
});

$('#all').mouseleave(function() {
  $('#div2').hide();
});
```

CSS:

```
#all {
  display: table;
}
#div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
#div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="all">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @re22, me desculpa. Mas não concordo com você em editar minha resposta, uma vez que o autor da pergunta já possuía a biblioteca jQuery em seu código. Se você for corrigir isso toda vez pode abrir todos os tópicos e colocar. Desnecessário!

Comment: Você pode [reverter](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/67213/revisions) qualquer edição feita nas suas respostas. Eu inclui o jQuery por você postar o código como *snippet*, se for pra postar algo que não funciona no browser então use o bloco de código normal.

Comment: Colega, o Jquery adicionado pelo @re22 ao exemplo é para funcionar, os Snippets são para reproduzir códigos, se você não vai executar nada, então não use o snippet use o icone `{ }`, achei a edição favorável ao poste. Removi o snippet que não é necessário no exemplo